# Excel VBA - Intercept AddIn Ribbon Click

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, ribbon

i would like to know if it is possible to intercept the event generated by the Ribbon Button of an Excel Addin. I'm able to access to the .xlam source but seems there is no code in it that intercept that event, so I think the handler is in the compiled component. Is my assessment correct? And then, if yes, can I intercept a click on a button of the ribbon, maybe using an Application Level Handler?

Thank you,

DD

Comment: - edit: thanks JosieP but i do not need another control, I would like to intercept existing ribbons controls.. i think that this addin does the trick (http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/02/27/how-an-office-add-in-intercepts-clicking-a-built-in-control/) but it seems to be for build-in only.. anyway i would like to develop it by myself..

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon button has a callback assigned to its onAction attribute - it will be a Sub in the addin that has an iribboncontrol parameter (or similar). If you have can view the customui part of the add-in's XML you will be able to determine exactly which callback is relevant.